# Why is this returning nan?

Tags: c++, c++11, nan

Code:

```
double v = (180*9.8)/(42*42);  // v should be 1.000000
printf("%f ",v);
cout<<asin(v);
```

Output:

```
1.000000
nan
```

I am using  64-bit mingw (win 7).

Comment: Have you checked `v > 1.0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because v is greater than 1 (when the (180*9.8)/(42*42) is evaluated using double precision floating point).

```
double v = (180*9.8)/(42*42); 

std::cout.precision(20);

cout << fixed << v << endl;
```

Output:

> 1.00000000000000022204
>   nan

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/092238f8119ac344)

To get away with the problem of finite precision can do below.

```
if (v > 1)
    v = 1;
if (v < -1)
    v = -1;
```

Answer (score 4):

`9.8` is a value that can't be represented exactly in floating point.   That means, the actual value stored is equal to `9.8 + delta`, where `delta` is a small value which may be positive or negative.

If `delta` is positive for your floating point representation (presumably IEEE), then `180*9.8` will be greater than `1764`, so the value of `v` will exceed `1`.  The only valid inputs for `asin()` are in the range `-1` to `1`.  Although the return value from `asin()` is not specified for values outside that range, a NaN is one way of reporting that.